# Changing Multiple select fields in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a two `f.select fields` in my form with the same object id. I am changing these fields by selecting the parent field using `javascript` and `CSS`.

```
<%= f.label :Service_Phase, 'Service Phase' %>    
<%= f.select :Service_Phase, [], { :prompt => 'None' }, class: 'select_phase', disabled: 'disabled' %>
<%= f.select :Service_Phase, (1..52), { :prompt => 'Select Week' }, class: 'select_week' %>
<%= f.select :Service_Phase, (1..12), { :prompt => 'Select Month' }, class: 'select_month' %>
```

I want to display the `select box disabled` with the text `'NONE'` by default and will change the `select_field` by the parent select field value. Is it any other neat way to do this in rails?  Because when i try to the check the value after selected the value of week in console, its display the empty string. I don't know where am doing wrong and how can I correct this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're referring to by parent select values, but right off the bat I would discourage using the same ID for multiple form elements, as it's bad practice and makes it difficult to select the using JS or CSS

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off just doing that with javascript/jquery. I don't believe rails has a built in way to enable a secondary select field based off the first.

Comment: I got that in javascript mate. I am using the `:service_phase` for all the select_fields. But its take only the first, I guess. When i type the value of the id in console. its display none.

Comment: Sorry I'm having difficulty understanding the problems. So are your select dropdowns showing but without IDs? If so the second parameter accepted in a select statement is the ID you want.

Comment: What do you want it to display? You're just passing it an empty array.

Comment: I want to display the selected value. The select_field is going to display only one from the three by some conditions. For example, if user can see the second select_field that is `week` displays the option of 1 to 52 integers. Once the user selected any integer, the `:service_phase` value should be the selected value.